# Amazon's FPS with Activemerchant

Tags: activemerchant, amazon-fps

I want to integrate Amazon's FPS service using Activemerchant.
I want to know that activemerchant support that?
and if yes, then can you please suggest any site to integrate Amazon's FPS?